# Find outliers in Hive - SemanticException

Tags: statistics, data-cleaning, hive

I'm trying to find some outliers on my database using HIVE and I'm using Standard Deviation technique. My query is:

```
SELECT ID
FROM data
WHERE ID < (AVG(ID) + STDDEV(ID))
  AND ID > (AVG(ID) - STDDEV(ID));
```

When I run this code I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 3:12 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'AVG'
```

How to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Hive doesn't let you use `avg` in a where clause. You can solve this with a subquery.

```
SELECT id
FROM 
    (SELECT id, AVG(id) as avg_id, STDDEV(id) as stddev_id FROM data)
WHERE id < avg_id + stddev_id AND id > avg_id - stddev_id
```